# Какой параметр передавать в метод для сохранения изображения?

Tags: android, bitmap

Есть такой код, взят из [примера](http://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-download-and-save-image-internally/).Пробую его использовать для того, чтобы сохранить во внутренней памяти изображение, загруженное из интернета.

```
public void saveImage(Context context, Bitmap b, String imageName) {
    FileOutputStream foStream;
    try {
        foStream = context.openFileOutput(imageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, foStream);
        foStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("saveImage", "Exception 2, Something went wrong!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что передавать в аргумент Bitmap b, чтобы метод работал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bitmap b` - это непосредственно изображение, которое будет сохраняться.

Думаю, что у вас имеется изображение в виде Drawable. Тогда для преобразования можно использовать функцию

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }
    }

    if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
    } else {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Если вы планируете сохранять ресурс (что странно), то

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                       R.resource);
```

Comment: Ресурс > Bitmap. Спасибо, не знал)

Comment: Ресурс не планирую сохранять, нужно сохранить загруженную из интернета картинку

Comment: Не проще тогда использовать DownloadManager для загрузки картинки файлом, как есть? Или даже без DM, http запросом?

Comment: да, попробую сделать так. Извините, только учусь